# Pipe Broken with PipeInputStream with kubernetes-client exec()

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I'm using the [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/) to try copy a directory from a pod, but I'm doing something wrong with the input stream from stdout.  I get a `java.io.IOException: Pipe broken` exception when it tries to `read()`.  I'm pretty sure that no data flows at all.  I'm half wondering if I need to read the InputStream on a separate thread or something?

The stream is created like this:

```
public InputStream copyFiles(String containerId,
                             String folderName) {

    ExecWatch exec = client.pods().withName(containerId).redirectingOutput().exec("tar -C " + folderName + " -c");

    // We need to wrap the InputStream so that when the stdout is closed, then the underlying ExecWatch is closed
    // also. This will cleanup any Websockets connections.
    ChainedCloseInputStreamWrapper inputStreamWrapper = new ChainedCloseInputStreamWrapper(exec.getOutput(), exec);

    return inputStreamWrapper;
}
```

And the InputStream is processed in this function

```
void copyVideos(final String containerId) {
    TarArchiveInputStream tarStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(containerClient.copyFiles(containerId, "/videos/"));
    TarArchiveEntry entry;
    boolean videoWasCopied = false;
    try {
        while ((entry = tarStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            String fileExtension = entry.getName().substring(entry.getName().lastIndexOf('.'));
            testInformation.setFileExtension(fileExtension);
            File videoFile = new File(testInformation.getVideoFolderPath(), testInformation.getFileName());
            File parent = videoFile.getParentFile();
            if (!parent.exists()) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            IOUtils.copy(tarStream, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            videoWasCopied = true;
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "{0} Video file copied to: {1}/{2}", new Object[]{getId(),
                    testInformation.getVideoFolderPath(), testInformation.getFileName()});
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, getId() + " Error while copying the video", e);
        ga.trackException(e);
    } finally {
        if (!videoWasCopied) {
            testInformation.setVideoRecorded(false);
        }
    }

}
```

The InputStream Wrapper class is just there to close the `ExecWatch` at the end once the InputStream is closed, it looks like this:

```
private static class ChainedCloseInputStreamWrapper extends InputStream {

    private InputStream delegate;
    private Closeable resourceToClose;

    public ChainedCloseInputStreamWrapper(InputStream delegate, Closeable resourceToClose) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.resourceToClose = resourceToClose;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return delegate.read();
    }

    public int available() throws IOException {
        return delegate.available();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        logger.info("Shutdown called!");
        delegate.close();

        // Close our dependent resource
        resourceToClose.close();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return delegate.equals(o);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return delegate.hashCode();
    }

    public int read(byte[] array) throws IOException {
        return delegate.read(array);
    }

    public int read(byte[] array,
                    int n,
                    int n2) throws IOException {
        return delegate.read(array, n, n2);
    }

    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        return delegate.skip(n);
    }

    public void mark(int n) {
        delegate.mark(n);
    }

    public void reset() throws IOException {
        delegate.reset();
    }

    public boolean markSupported() {
        return delegate.markSupported();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you connect to the apiserver? Are you connecting trough `kubectl proxy`, running in cluster, ...?

Comment: I'm running inside the cluster using a service account with the necessary roles created.  I'm running Openshift 1.4 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Full source at https://github.com/IPAustralia/zalenium/blob/40b253018b81e2d70b4742fd80a9ed8b19b1dae8/src/main/java/de/zalando/ep/zalenium/container/KubernetesContainerClient.java#L125. I have another function that runs an exec and writes to an outputstream which works fine:  https://github.com/IPAustralia/zalenium/blob/40b253018b81e2d70b4742fd80a9ed8b19b1dae8/src/main/java/de/zalando/ep/zalenium/container/KubernetesContainerClient.java#L144

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the tar command wrong, so it was causing a failure and the stdout PipeInputStream was dead locking. I managed to find a workaround for the deadlock. But the main reason for the failure was that I forgot to tell tar to actually do something! I at least needed a "." to include the current directory.

Comment: By any chance, do you remember the full tar command you used ?

Comment: https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/9f25e6081de136b16230ed2bbf376afe87d3fcbe/src/main/java/de/zalando/ep/zalenium/container/kubernetes/KubernetesContainerClient.java#L204